# Allowing for Regional Mobile House Ads

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, ads, adwhirl

I have a mobile app that allows the user to select what city/region they're in. I have implemented AdWhirl to maintain house ads, but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the concept of region.

Is there a way to maintain regional house ads that anyone has seen? Would I have to / be able to resort to implementing multiple SDK keys, one for each region?